# Mark form as invalid

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs4

On my field(s) in the FormPanel I added the listener `blur`. If this event occurs I execute the form validation as follows:

```
listeners:{
    scope: this,
    blur: function(field, value){
        var username = field;
        if (username.getValue() == '') {
            username.markInvalid('This field is required');
        } else {
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'users/validateForm',
                method: 'POST',
                params: 'username=' + username.getValue(),
                success: function(response, opts) {
                    var jsonData = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                    if (jsonData.msg.username != '') {
                        username.markInvalid(jsonData.msg.username);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}


buttons: [{
    text: 'Save',
    handler: function() {
        var form = this.up('form').getForm();
        if (form.isValid()) {
            alert('test');
        }
    },
    formBind:true
},{
    text: 'Cancel'
}]
```

As the documentation of Ext JS explains, the [markInvalid()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-method-markInvalid) function affects only the field itself. But I want also setting the form as invalid, so that the submit button is disabled when the form is invalid. Currently the function isValid() on the form always returns true, although the field(s) are marked as invalid.

My question now is, how can I achieve so that the form is also set as invalid with the code above?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: formBind doesn't work properly in version 4.0.2a. Try [this warkaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795511/extjs-simple-form-ignores-formbind/6798704#6798704).

Comment: I think the problem isn't the formBind config. In the workaround they used vtypes but I don't use this. When I click on the save button the function `isValid()` always returns `true`. I think this has nothing to do with the formBind method.

Comment: Form.isValid can always return true because it could have wrong fields cached in `form._boundItems`. So it may be the same problem as in the link I've posted.

Comment: I'm using the Ext JS version 4.0.7. Also with your code it doesn't work.

Comment: why not set allowBlank: false on the field?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make use of the `hasInvalidField()` method available with the form. For example:

```
var form = this.up('form').getForm();
if (form.hasInvalidField()) {
    alert('test');
}
```

From the docs:

> Returns true if the form contains any invalid fields.

Comment: Although the form has invalid fields, the function hasInvalidField() returns always false.